# Starling stage touch.phase moving sprite to current location of touch on stage

Tags: starling-framework

I'm trying to move a sprite object (the hero) to the current location of the began touch event on the stage.  Every time I touch on the stage it reads out the current `globalX` and `globalY` coordinates, but the sprite disappears from the stage so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
private function onTouch(e:TouchEvent):void
{
    var touch:Touch = e.getTouch(stage);
    if(touch)
    {
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN)
        {
            hero.x += touch.globalX;
            hero.y += touch.globalY;
            trace("Touched stage at position: " + touch)
        }
        else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED)
        {
            //The Touch ended (MouseUp)
        }
        else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.MOVED)
        {
            //dragging
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your hero sprite is added to Spirte with different size than the object you assigned the touch event. You need a sprite with for example screen size and the hero and the event added to it.

Hope that help :)